# How to optimize query with multiple subqueries in case when statements

Tags: sql

I am trying to rewrite a query to run faster. It currently has multiple subqueries inside case when statements. These are the tables involved and some sample data:

Each piece of equipment can have multiple equipment features. For example:

[image]
[image]

This is the query I currently have:

```
SELECT equipment_id 
, CASE  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) FROM equipment_feature WHERE feature_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '2ea' 
THEN 'Table 3.2-1, ' 
WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) FROM equipment_feature WHERE feature_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '4ea' 
THEN 'Table 3.2-2, ' 
WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) FROM equipment_feature WHERE feature_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '4so' 
THEN 'Table 3.2-3, '
WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) FROM equipment_feature WHERE feature_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = 'n/a' 
THEN 'Table 3.3-1, '
ELSE NULL 
END direction_table
, CASE  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) FROM equipment_feature WHERE feature_type_id = 62 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = 'gas' 
THEN 'Gas Powered '   
WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) FROM equipment_feature WHERE feature_type_id = 62 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = 'electric' 
THEN 'Electric Powered '
ELSE NULL 
END fuel_type
, CASE  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) FROM equipment_feature WHERE feature_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '2ea' 
THEN '2 East' 
WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) FROM equipment_feature WHERE feature_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '4ea' 
THEN '4 East'  
WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) FROM equipment_feature WHERE feature_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '4so' 
THEN '4 South' 
WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) FROM equipment_feature WHERE feature_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = 'n/a'    
THEN '(<= 300 hp)' 
ELSE NULL 
END  rating_class
from equipment e
```

And it returns the result like this
[image]

When I remove the select statements from my current query in hopes it would run faster

```
SELECT e.equipment_id
, CASE WHEN LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) = '2ea' and feature_type_id = 100001  
THEN 'Table 3.2-1, ' 
WHEN LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) = '4ea' and feature_type_id = 100001
THEN 'Table 3.2-2, ' 
WHEN LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) = '4so' and feature_type_id = 100001 
THEN 'Table 3.2-3, '
WHEN LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) = 'n/a' and feature_type_id = 100001 
THEN 'Table 3.3-1, '
ELSE NULL 
END direction_table  
, CASE  WHEN LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) = 'gas' and feature_type_id = 62 
THEN 'Gas Powered '   
WHEN LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature))= 'electric' and feature_type_id = 62
THEN 'Electric Powered '
ELSE NULL 
END fuel_type  
, CASE  WHEN LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) = '2ea' and feature_type_id = 100001 
THEN '2 East' 
WHEN LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) = '4ea' and feature_type_id = 100001 
THEN '4 East'  
WHEN LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) = '4so' and feature_type_id = 100001
THEN '4 South' 
WHEN LOWER(to_char(equipment_feature)) = 'n/a' and feature_type_id = 100001  
THEN '(<= 300 hp)' 
ELSE NULL 
END  rating_class
from equipment e
inner join equipment_feature ea on e.EQUIPMENT_ID = ea.EQUIPMENT_id
```

It gave me this as a result and is returning equipment_id with all different feature_type_id’s even though in my result output I want it to be like previous queries and only return the equipment_id once. For example, equipment 21606 feature_type_id of 62 that was highlight in the case when statements in the query returns Gas Powered in the Fuel Type column. For the same piece of equipment 21606, from feature_type_id 100001, it returns the direction table and rating class. I want all of this information to be returned in one equipment id in one row. I think it is because of the inner join but I am not sure how to change the logic of the case statement so this output it returned like it did in the previous query I had.
[image]
Any help optimizing the original case when statements or editing the query with removed select statements would be appreciated to have the same output results as the original query.

Comment: Could you change the second query to left outer join instead as … left outer join equipment_feature ea on e.EQUIPMENT_ID = ea.EQUIPMENT_id and ea.feature_type_id in( 100001,62)

Comment: You just need to put an aggregation function (e.g. MAX) round each case statement and group by equipment_id

Comment: @NickW would you be able to write an example of how that would look, I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: @NandalalSeth Adding the left outer join was able to get it to return each equipment_id once except for the pieces of equipment that have both feature_type_id's of 100001 and 62. Is there a way to get the data to return for both feature type id under one equipment id and not have it in separate rows?

Comment: Try doing both id in separate joins as … left outer join equipment_feature ea on e.EQUIPMENT_ID = ea.EQUIPMENT_id and ea.feature_type_id =100001 left outer join equipment_feature ea1 on e.EQUIPMENT_ID = ea1.EQUIPMENT_id and ea1.feature_type_id =62

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I’ve removed the contents of the case statements for brevity, you’ll need to add them back in):

```
SELECT e.equipment_id
, MAX(CASE WHEN … END) direction_table  
, MAX(CASE WHEN … END) fuel_type  
, MAX(CASE WHEN … END) rating_class
from equipment e
inner join equipment_feature ea on e.EQUIPMENT_ID = ea.EQUIPMENT_id
GROUP BY e.equipment_id
```